# How to authenticate android app and web application with single firebase application

Tags: android, database, firebase, web

I have an **android app** that connects with the firebase database. Now I want to connect web application with the same database that we build for android app and also show data in web application. Please lets me know this is possible if possible then tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Firebase allows you to access data from many platforms. You can use `django` to access the data using `python` or use `NodeJs` and access the data using `JavaScript`. I Personally suggest using `NodeJs` because it's easy to fix bugs and using firebase from `NodeJs` is simple.

```
// Import Admin SDK
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Get a database reference to our posts
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("server/saving-data/fireblog/posts");

// Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

This is as simple as writing a simple code.
Kindly refer to the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) for entire content.

Consider UpVoting the answer if it is helpfull
Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

You can use same firebase app for android, iOS, web or various backend, Check the following [web setup link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) for connecting your web application